# How can I run different commands in separate terminals using a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, scripts, tmux

I have access to an **Azure VM** where I intend to run *three* **Hyperledger Besu nodes**: *one boot node and two validator nodes*. To automate this setup, I've created a shell script.

First, I checked the terminal emulator by running:

```
echo "Terminal emulator: $TERM"
```

The output showed `xterm-256color`.

Based on this, I attempted to run the following command:

```
xterm -e "besu --network=devnet --bootnodes --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/BootNode/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8552 --rpc-ws-port=8553 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem; exec bash"
```

However, I encountered the error `xterm: command not found.`

I also tried the following command:

```
xterm -hold -e "publicmint --bootnodes --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/BootNode/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8552 --rpc-ws-port=8553 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem"
```

But encountered the same error: `xterm: command not found.`

When I checked for a list of terminals using:

```
update-alternatives --list x-terminal-emulator
```

I received the following error:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-terminal-emulator
```

Can anyone assist in resolving these errors?

I have used `tmux` but no luck:

```
# Run nodes in tmux sessions
run_bc_nodes() {
    local SESSION_NAME=$1
    local WINDOW_NAME=$2
    local COMMAND=$3

    echo "Running command in tmux session: $SESSION_NAME"

    # Start a new tmux session and create a window for the node
    if ! tmux has-session -t "$SESSION_NAME" 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Creating new tmux session: $SESSION_NAME"
        sudo tmux new-session -d -s "$SESSION_NAME" -n "$WINDOW_NAME" "$COMMAND"
    else
        echo "Tmux session already exists: $SESSION_NAME"
        sudo tmux new-window -t "$SESSION_NAME" -n "$WINDOW_NAME" "$COMMAND"
    fi

}

echo "############ Running Boot Node ############"
run_bc_nodes "BootNodeSession" "BootNode" "besu --bootnodes --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/BootNode/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8552 --rpc-ws-port=8553 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem"

echo "############ Running Validator-1 ############"
run_bc_nodes "Validator1Session" "Validator-1" "besu --bootnodes=enode://66ada5e1d7a6e63c05be9516d37990248e3db5e5a2d7e9ec13d2852266b4dcaa7c1ac876e5eaf560e2450fdcaf093622c012a30e04b44a757870fbf8526c20cd@127.0.0.1:30303 --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/Validator-1/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8554 --rpc-ws-port=8555 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --metrics-port=9441 --p2p-port=30101 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem"

echo "############ Running Validator-2 ############"
run_bc_nodes "Validator2Session" "Validator-2" "besu --bootnodes=enode://66ada5e1d7a6e63c05be9516d37990248e3db5e5a2d7e9ec13d2852266b4dcaa7c1ac876e5eaf560e2450fdcaf093622c012a30e04b44a757870fbf8526c20cd@127.0.0.1:30303 --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/Validator-2/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8556 --rpc-ws-port=8557 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --metrics-port=9442 --p2p-port=30102 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem"

echo "############ Running Validator-3 ############"
run_bc_nodes "Validator3Session" "Validator-3" "besu --bootnodes=enode://66ada5e1d7a6e63c05be9516d37990248e3db5e5a2d7e9ec13d2852266b4dcaa7c1ac876e5eaf560e2450fdcaf093622c012a30e04b44a757870fbf8526c20cd@127.0.0.1:30303 --genesis-file=build/uled-local.json --data-path=build/Validator-3/node --rpc-http-enabled=true --rpc-ws-enabled=true --rpc-http-port=8558 --rpc-ws-port=8559 --rpc-http-cors-origins=* --host-whitelist=* --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,TXPOOL,DEBUG, --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3 --metrics-enabled=true --metrics-host=0.0.0.0 --metrics-port=9443 --p2p-port=30103 --tx-pool-max-size=8000 --tx-pool-retention-hours=2 --revert-reason-enabled=true --logging=INFO --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-authentication-enabled=true --rpc-http-authentication-jwt-public-key-file=authKeys/puk.pem"

echo "****************** Script Completed ******************"
```

Output:

```
############ Running Boot Node ############
Running command in tmux session: BootNodeSession
Creating new tmux session: BootNodeSession
############ Running Validator-1 ############
Running command in tmux session: Validator1Session
Creating new tmux session: Validator1Session
############ Running Validator-2 ############
Running command in tmux session: Validator2Session
Creating new tmux session: Validator2Session
############ Running Validator-3 ############
Running command in tmux session: Validator3Session
Creating new tmux session: Validator3Session
Script completed
```

but can't find any tmux process.

Comment: Consider `screen`

Comment: Or use `tmux` ...

Comment: @ArturMeinild updated the question with tmux, but no luck with tmux

Comment: What does `tmux ls` show? And also, why do you need a new session for each command? You could use one session with 4 windows instead.

Comment: @ArturMeinild tried with one session also, but didn't worked. Got process id from ps aux but didn't saw any port available.

tmux ls
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default
for 1 session and multiple session. but command was executing error free